# Is SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE still used in sitecore 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-analytics

Does anyone know if the `SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE` is still used in Sitecore 7.5+?

The projects I'm working on at the moment only appears to be generating the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` but i can't find any documentation indicating that it's no longer utilized.

We are having various issues with getting the analytics data to identify users and suspect that this could indicate something is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE  is deprecated since first release of Sitecore 7.5. 
 Please check release history :

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC75.aspx

Above text is from release history document:

> The SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE is deprecated. The system no longer reads or sets this cookie.